# Is there an equivalent object in Javascript similar to Pair object from Java?

Tags: javascript, java

There is an object in *Java* that comes from [javafx.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) library. You can use it to return **2 value** as method return value. I wonder if there is an equivalent Object in *Javascript*. I can use regular `Map()` object for my purpose but I would like to know if there is something special for this purpose in Javascript too as it exists in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mentioned `Pair` object exists of a `key` and a `value` field.
As Javascript is a dynamic language I would suggest to simply use an object like

```
function () {
    const pair = {
        key: 'someKey',
        value: 'some value'
    };
    return pair;
}
```

or even

```
function () {
    const pair = {
        'someKey': 'someValue'
    };
    return pair;
}
```

But to my knowlege there is no dedicated pair object in the Javascript language.

Comment: It seems that there is not any dedicated object for this purpose but your solution works better than using Map object. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> There is an object in Java that comes from javafx.util library.

In fact, standard Java (JDK) does *not* have a Pair class. The class `javafx.util.Pair` is a [JavaFx](https://openjfx.io/) class, not a JDK class. Since JDK 11, JavaFx is a separate project maintained by OpenJFX community. The closest thing to a 'pair' notion JDK has is `Map.Entry`.

```
Map.Entry <String, Integer> pair = 
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry <>();
```

In JavaScript, defining a 'pair' is much simpler.

```js
var pair = {key1: "value1"};
console.log(pair.key1);
```